# Issues with time.sleep and Multithreading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am having an issue with the time.sleep() function in python. I am running a script that needs to wait for another program to generate txt files. Although, this is a terribly old machine, so when I sleep the python script, I run into issues with the other program not generating files. Is there any alternatives to using time.sleep()? I thought locking the thread might work but essentially it would just be a loop of locking the thread for a couple of seconds. I'll give some pseudo code here of what I'm doing.

```
While running:
    if filesFound != []:
         moveFiles
    else:
       time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Too pseudo, can't really help.  Anyway, to watch over a directory for new files, you could use pyinotify, http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify , `ReadDirectoryChangesW` in Windows (e.g. see http://tech-artists.org/wiki/Python_Recipes#Watch_a_Directory_for_Changes ), etc.

Comment: There isnt much else to say. Its pretty basic. I am really just looking for a way to wait for files to be created, without using up the cpu (so they can be created).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do a non-blocking wait is to use [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects):

```
import threading
dummy_event = threading.Event()
dummy_event.wait(timeout=1)
```

This can be `set()` from another thread to indicate that something has completed. **But** if you are doing stuff in another thread, you could avoid the timeout and event altogether and just `join` the other thread:

```
import threading

def create_the_file(completion_event):
    # Do stuff to create the file

def Main():
    worker = threading.Thread(target=create_the_file)
    worker.start()

    # We will stop here until the "create_the_file" function finishes
    worker.join()

    # Do stuff with the file
```

If you want an example of using events for more fine-grained control, I can show you that...

The threading approach won't work if your platform doesn't provide the threading module. For example, if you try to substitute the dummy_threading module, `dummy_event.wait()` returns immediately. Not sure about the `join()` approach.

If you are waiting for other processes to finish, you would be better off managing them from your own script using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module (and then, for example, using the [`wait`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method to be sure the process is done before you do further work).

If you can't manage the subprocess from your script, but you know the PID, you can use the [`os.waitpid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid) function. Beware of the `OSError` if the process has already finished by the time you use this function...

If you want a cross-platform way to watch a directory to be notified of new files, I'd suggest using a [GIO FileMonitor](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/class-giofilemonitor.html) from [PyGTK/PyGObject](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/). You can get a monitor on a directory using the [monitor_directory](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/class-giofile.html#method-giofile--monitor-directory) method of a [GIO.File](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/class-giofile.html).

Quick sample code for a directory watch:

```
import gio

def directory_changed(monitor, file1, file2, evt_type):
    print "Changed:", file1, file2, evt_type

gfile = gio.File(".")
monitor = gfile.monitor_directory(gio.FILE_MONITOR_NONE, None)
monitor.connect("changed", directory_changed) 

import glib
ml = glib.MainLoop()
ml.run()
```