# Put several Threads in sleep/wait not using Time.Sleep()

Tags: python, multithreading, tweepy

I wrote this function that handles the "rate limit error" of a Tweepy's cursor in order to keep downloading from Twitter APIs.

```
def limit_handled(cursor, user):
    over = False
    while True:
        try:
            if (over == True):
                print "Routine Riattivata, Serviamo il numero:", user
                over = False
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            print "Raggiunto Limite, Routine in Pausa"
            threading.Event.wait(15*60 + 15)
            over = True
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            print "TweepError"
            threading.Event.wait(5)
```

Since I am using serveral threads to connect I would like to stop each one of them when the RateLimitError error raises and restart them after 15 minutes.
I previously used the function:

```
time.sleep(x)
```

But I understood that doesn't work well for threads (the counter do not increase if the thread is not active) so I tried to use:

```
threading.Event.wait(x)
```

But it this error raises:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-15:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/xor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/xor/spyder/algo/HW2/hw2.py", line 117, in work
    storeFollowersOnMDB(ids, api, k)
  File "/home/xor/spyder/algo/HW2/hw2.py", line 111, in storeFollowersOnMDB
    for followersPag in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id = user, count=5000).pages(), user):
  File "/home/xor/spyder/algo/HW2/hw2.py", line 52, in limit_handled
    threading.Event.wait(15*60 + 15)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'wait'
```

How can I "sleep/wait" my threads being sure that they will wake up at the right moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it like this instead:

```
import threading
dummy_event = threading.Event()
dummy_event.wait(timeout=1)
```

also try google-ing next time first: [Issues with time.sleep and Multithreading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416160/issues-with-time-sleep-and-multithreading-in-python)

Comment: Thank you very much, I googled but with no success. Sorry for the waste of time!

Comment: Ah no problem, saw that you're just starting so i wont downvote. also i hope that you'll like this community c: